# How do I assert that an Option contains something in zio-test?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

I tried

```
assert(anOption)(contains("x"))
```

But that only works for Iterables such as List or Seq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
assert(anOption)(isSome(equalTo("x")))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest you to provide relevant details with your answer. That will be helpful for others to better understand your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @MuhammadTariq I had no problem to understand the answer.

Comment: @derpy, people from different age group, background and technical level use SO to get guidance. A lot of students and junior level devs/people are there who can't understand one-line code answers. Its better to properly describe question or answer that can easily be understandable to a large number of people.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be `assert(anOption)(equalTo(Some("x")))` - just using equality. Or if you want to use contains: `assert(isTrue(anOption.contains("x")))`  using the contains operator on option

Comment: Yeah, the first one works well and is simpler than the accepted answer. `isTrue` is not great because the failure message it will produce won't be descriptive.